# How do you extend Classes and Structs with Interfaces via extension in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I am making a utility library for various .Net Framework datastructures in C#. I am trying to add `ICloneable` to `Dictionary<>`. Is there a way to do this through an extension, like how you make extension methods?

To clarify further, in C# you can extend from already existing classes by making "Extension Methods" in a static class, like so:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void MyArrayExtension<T>(this T[] arg)
    {
        //Your code here...
    }
}
```

This allows you to do the function on all arrays, like so:

```
MyArray.MyArrayExtension();
```

You can create extension methods to extend all classes and structs, including those that you reference in DLLs like those for the .Net Framework. I am using this currently to help me design a utility library, with tons of useful extensions that I feel should have been implemented in C# in the first place.

When looking at `System.Linq`, it appears that Interfaces are somehow added to certain datastructure classes like `Array` and `List<>`, but only when the namespace is included. I am trying to figure out how this is done, as I cannot find any examples after searching online.

Comment: You can add a `.Clone` extension method but you cannot tuck on a whole interface, that is not possible. Unless you modify the class declaration, it will never implement `ICloneable`. What you're asking for is similar to what is called "shapes", where a class that implements all the necessary bits can be said to have "the shape of Y", which could be similar to an interface. You can read more about shapes [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164).

Comment: Make that an answer then, and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, this is not possible.

You can add the requisite `Clone` extension methods, but there is no way right now to tuck on a whole interface.

Remember that checking for support for an interface could be written in *existing* code like this:

```
if (dictionary is ICloneable cloneable)
    var clone = cloneable.Clone();
```

But this would not work with just extension something as the underlying type *does not in fact implement the interface*.

---

There are some ongoing efforts in this line of thought:

- [Extension everything](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11159)
- [Shapes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164)

I have no idea how good they manage to get these things so whether it could potentially solve this in the future is a bit up in the air.

---

Note that you could do this using decoration, but it might be a bit of work and it would require you to construct your dictionaries using a different type:

```
public class CloneableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ICloneable
{
    ... methods and properties that delegate to base.XYZ

    public object Clone() => new ...
}
```

Everywhere you construct your object you would then have to write this:

```
var dictionary = new CloneableDictionary<...>();
```

instead of:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<...>();
```

Since `CloneableDictionary` inherits `Dictionary`, you could drop it into variables and parameters that already exists, even if their type is kept as `Dictionary<...>`, but if you forget that you're really storing other dictionary types in there and construct new, normal, non-cloneable, dictionaries some places it may quickly fall down.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, though it is upsetting that I cannot achieve the desired result. The example you show with code is exactly the problem I'm worried about. The Prototype Pattern requires the interface to be implemented, and making the `Dictionary` class not be `ICloneable` will make things much more complicated for users down the line.

Comment: Note that `ICloneable` is a horrible interface and should not be used. Almost every time someone uses this interface they expect it to behave different than what it does *because peoples expectations to cloning things do not align*. For instance, do you expect it to just clone the dictionary, or should the cloned dictionary also contain cloned keys and cloned values? What about objects referred to from these cloned values, should they be cloned as well? You're almost always better off writing your own clone method exactly like you expect it to be.

Comment: I posted the above comment as a comment because this is my opinion, and should be seen in a different light compared to my answer which is more listing why you cannot do it and existing efforts in this kind of thing.

Comment: I think I may do the `ICloneable` dictionary suggestion you just added. Seems to be the best solution to this problem.